# Silverstripe Editors can not edit own DataObjects

Tags: php, permissions, content-management-system, silverstripe, data-objects

My problem is that editors can't edit or create certain DataObjects I created for page I built. Some are editable and some aren't. And if I switch language, it's a multi-language site, then the Input fields don't even appear.

Examples:
I have a class for links to display a linklist

- German -> Editors can edit and create
- Englisch -> No fields in popup

Other class that manages Downloads

- German -> Show: yes, edit & create: no
- Englisch -> No fields in popup

Could anybody hint me to where the problem may be?

EDIT2: File with code attached in comments

Edit:
Here's my translate Function:

```
public function getCMSFieldTranslated(FieldSet $fieldset, array $transFields) {
    // If a translation exists, exchange them with
    // original/translation field pairs
    $translation = $this->getTranslation(Translatable::default_locale());
    if($translation && $this->Locale != Translatable::default_locale()) {
        $transformation = new Translatable_Transformation($translation);

        foreach($transFields as $fieldName => $field) {
            $fieldset->replaceField($fieldName, $transformation->transformFormField($field));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you applied some canCreate() or similar functions to your dataobjects? could you provide some code excerpts?

Comment: I did not use canCreate. Here's the Link class as example http://dl.dropbox.com/u/134993/Link.php Could you help me wich params I would have to pass to canCreate if a editor needs rights to edit?

Comment: TableListField.php function Can($mode) returns false on $this->isReadOnly(), but where do I set this correctly and why does it work in german?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the fields in the popup to be translated.
Look at the translation documentation on this.
http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/translation#translating-custom-properties

In the example, it use the getCMSFields function, but use the same strategy for the getPopupFields().

If that don't help you, post your model and controller.

Have a good day.

Comment: I've added a function getCMSFieldsTranslated to Page.php. Would that mean I have to add this function for all may classes that derive from Page.php? Translation of custom properties seems to work. Just not my own Dataobjects...

Comment: I also reviewed and saw that I don't need a translation of an existing dataobject. Just create a new one for the pageID of the english page